# Formatting a cover page

Tags: titles

I was looking for some help creating a template for a cover page (an example is provided below), if you are simply able to help me look for any packages that would be useful I would appreciate it immensely, since I am kind of new to Latex[image].

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Start from checking this post. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage